# Pass a value generated in Mocha-before to express app

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, web3js

Im working with express and mocha for test. 
From Express Im getting info from an smart contract deployed in ropsten. So the address is always the same. I have that address in a config file.

For local testing, I want to use testrpc and deploy the smart contract before each test. So when I need to pass the address of the deploy to the express app.

My code is:

Test.js

```
beforeEach(async function () {
    index = DeployContract() //this returns a random address 
    server = await app.listen(3000)
})
```

In the app

```
const CONFIG = require('../config.json')
const contex =  {
  indexAddress: CONFIG.indexAddress, // or .env
  gasMargin: CONFIG.gasMargin,
  web3: web3
}

router.get('/manager', (req, res, next) => {
  const manager = new Manager(contex) //this must be the address returned beforeEach
  // do something
  res.send(200)
})
```

I need need to use the genereated address for `indexAddress: CONFIG.indexAddress`, so I can use the contex in the constructor.

Comment: Instead of sharing what your code is similar to, code you share what it is *exactly* so we can see what you have done to help you further.

Comment: If the address is always the same, why don't you put it in a config file and load the proper value based on process.env?

Comment: The address change befeore each test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reference to a global variable where you will save the address generated by DeployContract(), some example would be:

file: contract address

```
let address = "" 
export default address
```

then in your beforeEach hook you should import this variable, and set the address to it.
And in your app you should aim to this variable